# App crashes everytime on cold start after I cleared the data and cache

Tags: android, facebook

I am new to Android as well as Fb sdk. So do please post any suggestion or reference.

It was working fine until I cleared the data. Now the app is crashing during cold start. I have checked the login status but am still confused with the lifecycle of the `currentAccessToken`. Are there any docs or lifecycle diagram of `accessToken` which I could follow. Here's the code which I have been trying.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

        initialiseFacebookSdk();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        animShow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_up);
        mSignIn.startAnimation(animShow);
        mLogoImg.setAlpha(200);
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null && Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null;
    }

    private void initialiseFacebookSdk() {

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                String userId = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();
                String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();

                Log.d(TAG, "UserId:  " + userId + "\n" + "AccessToken:  " + accessToken + "");

                // Add code here for sending userId and access token to api

                Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, HomeScreenActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Snackbar.make(getCurrentFocus(), "Login cancelled!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setActionTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.snackbar_action_color))
                        .show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Snackbar.make(getCurrentFocus(), "Login error. Retry!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setActionTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.snackbar_action_color))
                        .show();

                Log.d(TAG, error + "");
            }
        });

    }


    @OnClick({R.id.sign_fb_splash_linear})
    void onClick() {

        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (isLoggedIn() ) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, HomeScreenActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else {

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.debdeep.partyhere.activity.SignInActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.view.ViewGroup.getContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3588)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3631)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.view.ViewGroup.getContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.<init>(Snackbar.java:183)
                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:215)
                                                                      at com.debdeep.partyhere.activity.SignInActivity$1.onError(SignInActivity.java:101)
                                                                      at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.finishLogin(LoginManager.java:579)
                                                                      at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:216)
                                                                      at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:159)
                                                                      at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:82)
                                                                      at com.debdeep.partyhere.activity.SignInActivity.onActivityResult(SignInActivity.java:129)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6235)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3584)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3631) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

Comment: Are you using a Samsung device to test your app? I have found an issue with Samsung phones that causes issues with restarting/starting your application. If so, I haven't found a fix yet.

Comment: No I am using a Yu manufacturer's device.

Comment: Do you think there's something wrong with the logic ?

Comment: Post your logcat please

Comment: I have posted the logcat, please take a look.

Comment: Is the code that you pasted from HomeScreenActivity?

Answer (score 0):

First, put initialiseFacebookSdk(); right after  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
It has to be the first line.
Second, "this.getApplicationContext()" might be a mistake just write getApplicationContext().

Furthermore review this link and guid if you haven't already:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens